# What architecture would you use to store 10 billion MIME messages and make it deletable and full text searchable incl. attachments

Tags: database, architecture, full-text-search, mime, file-storage

I would like to use components that are free for commercial use.

I looked at a Lucene and MongoDB combo but wonder if there are better approaches, ideally a single system.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Do you process the 10b messages in one huge batch load or is it transactional?

Comment: Still too broad... how many messages do you retrieve in e.g. 1 sec? Do you have to index the files in batch or 'real-time'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx can also handle billions of documents http://sphinxsearch.com/info/powered/

(although I also use Lucene and cannot tell whether Sphinx is better)